# Beyond import: Is there an option to keep LinkedIN profile in sync with SO Careers profile?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I maintain my LinkedIN profile meticulously and I've been using it as my only resume in the last ~8 years.

Now don't get me wrong - it is great that SO careers exists and I'd love to have them both, but the only thing stopping me is that I want to maintain the information in a single place.

Is there a way to have it automatically synchronized on a regular basis, instead of doing just a 'one time import'?

Comment: related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274247/re-sync-linkedin-profile It looks like they can't use the linkedin api anymore due to terms of service.